# How would I write a test class for this get set property class?

Tags: code-coverage

I am new to apex, and need to write a number test classes to cover code to get it all in prod.(Part of a complicated mapping/quoting thing built by our partner unexpectedly cut off during COVID19)

```java
public with sharing class GetRoute {

         /**
         * Webkul Software.
         *
         * @category  Webkul
         * @author    Webkul
         * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2016 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
         * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
         */

    public static string startpoint{get{
        startpoint = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('startpoint');
        return startpoint;
    } set;}
    public static string endpoint{get{
        endpoint = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('endpoint');
        return endpoint;
    } set;}
    public void nothing(){}   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Unit testing is a common topic here, so the community has written several questions and answers under the [tag:canonical-qa] tag to handle the common questions. If you're not sure where to start, those questions (and the apex testing trailhead module) are the best places to start.

Comment: The gist of it is: 1) Create the data you need to get your code to work (and in this situation, use `Test.setCurrentPage()` and `ApexPages.currentPage().getParmeters()`). 2) Explicitly call the code you want to test. 3) Gather the results, and make assertions to verify that the results are what you expect.

Comment: Thank you @DerekF - I will look some more. Before actually joining (so I could post) I was searching for something that helped me understand how to get started with this one! I think it's the 'isTest is not allowed on properties' error I was getting that I didn't find anything that made me decide to post for assistance.

Comment: @ChristiKane That's a problem with your unit test, not this code. We'd need to see that to figure out how to help you.

Comment: @sfdcfox All I did so far is add the code to a new test class and add '@istest' before the class and methods (which I discovered is a property). Again - New at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a unit test, you need to actually access the code being tested. Your unit test would look something like this:

```
@isTest class GetRouteTest {
  @isTest static void test() {
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(Page.GetRoute);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().putAll(
      new Map<String, String> {
        'startpoint' => '12345',
        'endpoint' => '23456'
      }
    );
    System.assertEquals('12345',GetRoute.startpoint);
    System.assertEquals('23456',GetRoute.endpoint);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Covered all but the line 'public void nothing' :)  85% coverage!

Comment: @ChristiKane your new to Apex so take to heart: covering lines is not the focus. Covering logic and all variations including negative tests, unexpected variable values like nulls tests, etc. covering lines is a result of covering logic. If you focus just on covering line all you are doing is testing the light switch can be turned on but not checking that the light actually illuminated.